# How can I cast column and use between function together in a query in postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

```
select cast (xyz as numeric) 
from clustering
where xyz between 100 and 500
order by xyz asc;
```

Comment: Statement failed but why ?

Comment: Please post what is the error message.  Also can you share table structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast your column in your `WHERE` clause as well:

```
select cast(xyz as numeric) 
from clustering
where cast(xyz as numeric) between 100 and 500
order by xyz asc;
```

Comment: Thank you very very much :)

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer was a good solution to your question, please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the check-mark so the question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, I would write this as:

```
select xyz::numeric
from clustering
where xyz::numeric between 100 and 500
order by xyz ;
```

You might want to also use `order by xyz::numeric` as well.